# cgal poisson surface reconstruction

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I installed CGAL on linux with `sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev`. 
When compiling I kept getting the error `fatal error: CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h: No such file or directory` even though all other CGAL related headers loaded fine.

Is the poisson surface reconstruction not included in the liccgal-dev? Can anyone suggest alternatives to convert point clouds to a polyhedron mesh?

Below shows all the headers that I used (without the poisson surface reconstruction, the rest compiled fine)

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/poisson_surface_reconstruction.h>
```

`
And below is my CMakeLists.txt:

`
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
    project(mapless_oa)

```
## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
geometry_msgs
roscpp
rospy
sensor_msgs
std_msgs
laser_geometry
tf
pcl_ros
)

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES mapless_oa
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(laser2pc src/laser2pc.cpp)
add_executable(ptcld2convex src/ptcld2convex.cpp )

target_link_libraries(laser2pc ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(ptcld2convex ${catkin_LIBRARIES} CGAL gmp mpfr)
```

}
`

Comment: What version of ubuntu/debian/whatever do you have, and what version of CGAL? You can look at the content of `/usr/include/CGAL/` to check if there are many files, including poisson_surface_reconstruction.h.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem! Had to install CGAL from source.